# DataTable add a button to each row

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, datatable, datatables

Using DataTable API, I am creating a table & adding a button - 'Click' to each table row. Example link below:

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

On the click I am changing text to 'View'. So, after page reload, rather all the buttons displaying default text - 'Click', how to render some buttons with text - 'Click' while the others which were clicked with - 'View'. Experts please share your inputs!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {
          "type": "get",
          "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",            
          "dataType": "json",
          "dataSrc": function (json) {
                 var return_data = new Array();
                 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                     return_data.push({
                         'userId': json[i].userId,
                         'id': json[i].id,
                         'title': "Test Data"
                     })
                 }
                 return return_data;
          }
      },
      "columns": [
             { 'data': 'userId' },             
             { 'data': 'id' },
             { 'data': 'title' },
             { 'data': null }
        ],
       "columnDefs": [
         { targets: 0, className: 'dt-body-center'},
         { targets: 1, className: 'dt-body-center'},
         { targets: 2, className: 'dt-body-center'},
         { targets: -1, width: "150px", 
           className: 'dt-body-center', defaultContent:         
           "<button id='btnDetails'>Click</buttom>" }
        ]});

  $('#example tbody').on('click', '[id*=btnDetails]', function () {
       $(this).text("View");
  });  
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>        
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
  <script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table id="example" class="display cell-border compact stripe"    style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th> 
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_how to render some buttons with text 'Click' while the others with 'View'_" - What are the criteria for determining whether to display `Click` vs. `View`?

Comment: On the click I am changing text to 'View'. So, after page reload, rather all the buttons displaying default text - 'Click', I want to render some buttons with text - 'Click' while the others which were clicked with - 'View'

Comment: Thank you. You can add your notes to the question. It's still not especially clear to me what you want. It sounds like you will need to save that "what was clicked" state somewhere - but is it the state per browser session, or system-wide, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to save the state so that after terminating the browser or page reload, button text should persist and display 'View'. Since, we are using defaultContent to add button so each time it is displaying 'Click'.

Comment: Yes, but what state? Per browser session? Globally? Should user A see what user B clicked on, when user A refreshes their page? And please add your updates to the question. (If it's just per browser, you can research using the Javascript session storage API.)

Comment: It should be global. Per browser session, I was able to change text using jquery - $(this).text("View");. And Yes, both User A & B should be able to see the changes after page refresh. I tried using Local Storage but didn't work because by default each row has a button with same id so I'm not sure how to implement this in DataTables.

Comment: If storage needs to be global (user A sees user B's changes & vice versa), then you probably need a server-side solution (e.g. a database, or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a database to persist the state of button. Check below link for server-side processing:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: You don't need to use DataTables' server side processing to save state in a database.